# Python Array Question(Programming)

Tags: python, arrays, perl, syntax

What does the [] mean?
Also how can I identify variables as empty arrays in python?
Thanks!

```
perl: xcoords = ()
```

How do I translate that?

Comment: That's not Perl. The perl version would be: @xcoords = ();

Comment: sorry, i forgot to add the array sign, how should i translate that

Comment: do you mean `[]` or `()`?  in perl, they do very different things there.  Please copy and paste the actual code you want to know about or your question becomes pretty meaningless.

Comment: how would @Xcoords = () in perl, be translated to python

Answer (score 3):

[] - is an empty list in Python and is the same as calling list() e.g. [] == list()
To check that list is empty you can use len(l) or:

```
listV = [] # an empty list
if listV:
    # do something if list is not empty
else:
    # do something if list is really empty
```

To read more about list you can use [the following link](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

Comment: all empty containers evaluate to `False`

Comment: @tbilisidavid or you may use `len(emptyList)` to determine if the list is empty or not, in case you just want to check.

Answer (score 0):

Lists are like C++ arrays with some difference. One of difference is they can cary different types even lists. to check if lists is empty

```
lists = []
len(lists)
lists[0]= "More of me"
len(lists)
```

More check [Python official](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/introduction.html#lists) tutorial and above Docs